# Example of Custom Class on the Transformable property of Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

When you create a `Transformable` property on core data, you generally add the `NSValueTransformer` code to the entity's class and fill its name on the `Value Transformer` field of the data model inspector, but what about the `Custom Class` field? What is the purpose of that field? Can you give a simple example?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Custom Class" controls what happens to this property when Xcode generates subclasses of / extensions on `NSManagedObject`. If you leave this field blank, your `snapshot` field will be declared as an `NSObject`. If you fill in a class name, Xcode will declare the attribute as whatever class name you enter.

In practice that means that if you make `snapshot` transformable, leave that field blank, and then Xcode generates a subclass for you, the property will be declared as:

```
@NSManaged public var snapshot: NSObject?
```

On the other hand if you fill in that field, for example by typing `UIImage` there, then when Xcode generates the subclass the property will be declared as:

```
@NSManaged public var snapshot: UIImage?
```

Filling in a class name allows the compiler to check your assignments so that if, for example, the property is a `UIImage`, you don't mistakenly try to assign an `NSData` to it.

**Update**: If you're using Swift, you also need to add a value for the "module" field in the property configuration, just below "custom class". For the `snapshot` property here, do this:

[image: Core Data transformable property with custom class set to UIImage and module set to UIKit]

When you do this, the generated source code will include `import UIKit` so that the code will compile. Thanks to @grego for pointing this out in a comment.

Comment: What? Your explanation melted my brain. I could not understand a single word...  Care to expand your answer, add examples, etc.? Thanks.

Comment: Expanded, added more detail.

Comment: Ok, I understand your expanded explanation, thanks for that, but what I don't get is this: when I define the transformer I have to declare it as a `NSValueTransformer`. Ok, that is a subclass of `NSObject` but what I don't get is how a transformer class can be of kind UIImage... (??!)

Comment: It's not the transformer class. It's the type of that attribute in the `NSManagedObject` subclass.

Comment: not getting that. Do you know any code I can download to see that in action? Thanks

Comment: **This field has nothing at all to do with your value transformer.** It is solely about how the `snapshot` attribute is declared. It's a way of telling Xcode what type to use in a variable declaration. As for code, the examples I gave demonstrate the difference. What are you "not getting" about how those declarations differ?

Comment: Wouldn't the CoreDataProperties.h complain because the generated file didn't forward declare the custom class? I'm on Objective-C if that makes a difference.

Comment: @CyberMew In Objective-C, Xcode will generate a forward declaration. In this case it would add `@class UIImage;`.

Comment: Swift doesn't import UIKit for us or have a way to forward declare the class in the case of a UIImage. How can I tell codegen to import it? Do I need to use a manual class definition for this?

Comment: I updated the answer to cover that